# producer.poll(0) won't produce any message but producer.flush() works

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

when I use `producer.flush()` it works but with poor performance according to [kafka confluent  issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/137) , but as suggested I use `producer.poll(0)` but no message will produce to topics , is there any config needed or I missing something here?

```
self.producer.produce(topic.value, data.encode('utf-8'), callback=self.delivery_report)

self.producer.poll(0)  # -> doesn't work
self.producer.flush()  # -> works
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate the question? The question does not seem to be clear

Comment: @ArunGowda question is clear , is there any config needed for `poll()` to produce message into topics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Messages are not sending to kafka because there is no time to do this. Your app is terminating early.

This will work:

```
self.producer.produce(topic.value, data.encode('utf-8'), callback=self.delivery_report)
timer.sleep(1) -- sleep for one seconds. 
self.producer.poll(0)
```

Producer has two buffers. 1st sending buffer, 2nd response buffer (response from kafka).

method `produce(...)` - is adding new message to sending buffer. By default background thread is trying to send messages as soon as possible but still it needs a time to do this.

method `poll(0)` - is checking response buffer and executing callback method. If buffer is empty nothing happens.

method `flush()` - is checking both buffers, until all messages will be proceeded and it is executing callback methods. Use this method before exiting app.

Example usage.

```
def send(topic,message,callback_report):
   producer.produce(topic,message,callback=callback_report)
   producer.pool(0) // execute callback for previous messages,  

for msg in big_collection_of_messages:
  send('blabla',msg,delivery_report)


producer.flush()
//END OF APPLICATION
```

Note. This explanation is a big simplification.

Comment: That was a very helpful explanation, not many places explain this sending vs response buffers. Thank you!